# Hangfire server enqueueing incorrect jobs

Tags: c#, hangfire

I'm seeing an issue with the RecurringJob type when I have two processes, each with their own BackgroundJobServer instance running, queueing each others jobs. For example, server 1 handles jobs in a queue named "server1" and server 2 handles jobs in a queue named "server2" (same database). I set this up using the BackgroundJobServerOptions.Queues property. Each server processes it's own queue jobs just fine. But, when I stop Server 2, and look at the dashboard. I notice that the Server 2 jobs are not being processed, which is correct, but they are still being created and put into an enqueued status. Why is server 1 adding jobs to the "server2" queue?? Shouldn't server 1 only be concerned with the jobs in the "server1" queue?

If I don't want this to happen I have to make sure the processes do not reference the others code library, then it won't queue up the other servers jobs....but, instead it throws an exception that gets caught and eaten, which doesn't seem very correct...

Can someone tell me if this is expected behavior or if it's a bug?

Comment: file an issue with the repo; SO is not a support forum

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama - I have submitted it on hangfires support forum, but I haven't got any responses. Just curious....what is the purpose of SO if it's not to help others with the technologies they are working?